# Number of integer solutions of $\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{y}=\frac{1}{2016}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How can we find number of integer solutions of

$\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{y}=\frac{1}{2016}$

I want to ask what approach in general should be followed in such types of question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:$$\frac{1}{x} +\frac{1}{y} = \frac{x+y}{xy} = \frac{1}{2016}$$

$$\Rightarrow 2016x-xy = -2016y $$

$$\Rightarrow x  = 2016\cdot \bigg(\frac{y}{y-2016}\bigg)$$

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Yes. Thank You.

Comment: Not a problem! :)

Answer (score 4):

Write it as $$x = \dfrac{2016 y}{y-2016} = 2016 + \dfrac{2016^2}{y - 2016}$$
So $y - 2016$ is one of the divisors of $2016^2$.

Answer (score 2):

In general, for $\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{y}=\frac{1}{c}$, ve have $0=xy-cx-cy$. Then $c^2=xy-cx-cy+c^2$ or $c^2=(x-c)(y-c)$.

Now, if $c=p_1^{\alpha_1}p_2^{\alpha_2}...p_n^{\alpha_n}$, we have $c^2=p_1^{2\alpha_1}p_2^{2\alpha_2}...p_n^{2\alpha_n}$.

In your case $2016=2^53^27$. Can you conclude?

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{y}=\frac{1}{2016}\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\frac{y}{xy}+\frac{x}{xy}=\frac{1}{2016}\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\frac{x+y}{xy}=\frac{1}{2016}\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$xy=2016(x+y)\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$xy-2016x=2016y\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$x\left(y-2016\right)=2016y\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$x=\frac{2016y}{y-2016}$$

With $y\ne2016$ and $y\ne0$.

Comment: What happened to the condition that $x$ and $y$ are integers?